# Необходимо удалить из двумерной матрицы строку с минимальной суммой элементов

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, память

Я думаю, что удалить строку можно, сделав цикл на нахождение индекса строки с минимальной суммой и присвоив этот индекс какой-нибудь переменной, а затем сделать сдвиг всех строк с перевыделением памяти, но у меня не получается это грамотно написать. Если кто-то может подать идею или дополнить ниже представленный код - буду предельно благодарен.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

// печать массива
void printMt(int* A, int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            printf("%d\t", *(A + m * i + j));
            //printf("%d\t", ar[m*i + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
// ввод элементов матрицы
void inputMt(int* A, int n, int m,int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            scanf_s("%d", A + m * i + j);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m, smin = 0, s=0, imin;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    printf("\nКол-во строк: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("\nКол-во столбцов: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    int* A = (int*)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    printf("\n\n Введите элементы массива: \n\n");
    inputMt(A, n, m, s);
    printf("\n\n Исходный массив: \n\n");
    printMt(A, n, m);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я дополнил ваш код так, чтобы он в итоге решал поставленную задачу:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##tVTdbhJBFL6fpzjBaHbZRUrrb4EmxFt8AjFm5UeH7A7N7uKFlsQSrRfYG6@M8SEqKQlaW19h5onwnBkozEKjNXEJM7Nnvjlzzne@s81CMwzEi9nsBhfNsN9qQyVJWyF/fvvlHlvaUh61bQuieM82hb1mEGZgURCimWysWAT5S07UB3mihuojyJ@4OFSHcirH8oS96vEW7MdcpI9TB8c81HzAGYSZIhfeMMCn04uBAMChCltlnCogyuB5fIGwUF2D6iIqIlR3FUWPvrPj5G62GmnOh7xTAw8iyKNjD7quW7bQxWIGH8RPoryGPl2BDljWfUPk5vsDNtBkjPF3IU9BHcszOUE6JvJcDdE0NtwM1Vs5VUdqZLjhYr9/FTc@jcn/YihpBkInjOna5GQTptSYjijgwnGZ8aND8aHrU7yRD0nEBd2JqyoOHF@rhZLxlbRToyOn/uhZrV73IRf3F8wtuZRfkKezAjEIKCKi6kL@2IUFcjXkW@KPx@lNflNHRP4VTqK50dCP4etCuEbgjkBKiJaEv273OrTlrl3aECA/4ZUTeYp1HcpJpvJqlOmJXaBDucuLTf1rlzRuvOEznn9PukKXI/ndcmk7XDTb3CFar6GeRG/@jZhsKYFXnbcY15TZKuId9ELqqMAWHBwgvKLVsqZIo6DE7k1urHxdlcxyvochbuwEypgQ86ShAKW1xK@TLT3ZZGGRv0MtVHI3sLD8eFA6JozVROyCf9XFnqp39LHAP3UCikee/4MAyBq3034sqLgDNpvtwA67A3fhHivBNq7vwwN4@Bs)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <malloc.h>

// печать массива
void printMt(int* A, int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            printf("%d\t", *(A + m * i + j));
            //printf("%d\t", ar[m*i + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
// ввод элементов матрицы
void inputMt(int* A, int n, int m,int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            scanf("%d", A + m * i + j);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m, smin = 0, s=0, imin=-1;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    printf("\nКол-во строк: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nКол-во столбцов: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    int* A = (int*)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    printf("\n\n Введите элементы массива: \n\n");
    inputMt(A, n, m, s);
    printf("\n\n Исходный массив: \n\n");
    printMt(A, n, m);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        s = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            s += *(A + i * m + j);
        if (imin < 0 || s < smin) {
            smin = s;
            imin = i;
        }
    }

    if (imin >= 0) {
        for (int i = imin; i < n - 1; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                *(A + i * m + j) = *(A + (i + 1) * m + j);
        }
        n = n - 1;
    }

    printf("\n\n Модифицированный массив: \n\n");
    printMt(A, n, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Вход:

```
Кол-во строк: 3
Кол-во столбцов: 3
Введите элементы массива: 
4 5 6
1 2 3
7 8 9
```

Выход:

```
 Исходный массив: 

4   5   6   
1   2   3   
7   8   9   

 Модифицированный массив: 

4   5   6   
7   8   9
```